# Format an English-language count of items

Tags: python, java

I started reading Robert Martin's *Clean Code*. I'm trying to "translate" all his examples into Python, so I can understand them better since my knowledge of Python is greater than that of Java.

This class formats a count in into a natural English sentence:

### Java original code of the book

> ```java
> public class GuessStatisticsMessage {
>     private String number;
>     private String verb;
>     private String pluralModifier;
>
>     public String make(char candidate, int count) {
>         createPluralDependentMessageParts(count);
>         return String.format(
>             "There %s %s %s%s", 
>             verb, number, candidate, pluralModifier);
>     }
>
>     private void createPluralDependentMessageParts(int count) {
>         if (count == 0) {
>             thereAreNoLetters();
>         } else if (count == 1) {
>             thereIsOneLetter();
>         } else {
>             thereAreManyLetters(count);
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void thereAreManyLetters(int count) {
>         number = Integer.toString(count);
>         verb = "are";
>         pluralModifier = "s";
>     }
>
>     private void thereIsOneLetter() {
>         number = "1";
>         verb = "is";
>         pluralModifier = "";
>     }
>
>     private void thereAreNoLetters() {
>         number = "no";
>         verb = "are";
>         pluralModifier = "s";
>     }
> }
> ```

### My Python version

```py
class GuessStatsMessage:
    def __init__(self, candidate, count):
        self.candidate = candidate
        self.count = count
        self.__number = self.__verb = self.__plural_modifier = ''

    def make_message(self):
        self.__create_pluraldependant_message_parts()
        guess_message = (f'There {self.__verb} '
                         f'{self.__number} '
                         f'{self.candidate}{self.__plural_modifier} ')
        print(guess_message)

    def __create_pluraldependant_message_parts(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            self.__there_are_no_letters()
        elif self.count == 1:
            self.__there_is_one_letter()
        else:
            self.__there_are_many_letters()

    def __there_are_no_letters(self):
        self.__number = 'no'
        self.__verb = 'are'
        self.__plural_modifier = 's'

    def __there_is_one_letter(self):
        self.__number = '1'
        self.__verb = 'is'
        self.__plural_modifier = ''

    def __there_are_many_letters(self):
        self.__number = str(self.count)
        self.__verb = 'are'
        self.__plural_modifier = 's'
```

It should be used as follows:

```py
message = GuessStatsMessage('Foo', 10)
message.make_message()
# output: There are 10 Foos
```

Comment: For those who don't know the book, it would help to know what is the goal of the original code.  Any simplifying assumptions, etc. (no unusual plurals like oxen or mothers-in-law).  It looks like a reasonable translation (except make_message prints and the original returned a string).  But Python is not Java.  For example, in Python one would would define a `__str__()` method and maybe a `__format__()` method instead of `make_message()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it. I will update the question (I don't know if I should call it like that here, in Code Review) to show what is the goal of the original code of Uncle Bob. @RootTwo

Comment: I get it: You translated the Java private methods to `__double_underscore` in Python. But be careful: Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. But `__private` names don't work the same way as in Java. Actually I don't think this is a good practice in Python at all.

Comment: Thanks for letting that clear, Peter. I appreciate it. I knew about it, and about name mangling, but I don't really know another way of actually hiding those attributes and methods for the users of `GuessStatsMessage` class. @PéterLeéh

Comment: So do you want to know if your Python translation is a correct translation or if the translation is *pythonic*?

Comment: The second one: I wanted you guys to check how Pythonic is that version of the example. I'm especially unsure about initializing the private attributes. I also thought about making it using @classmethod and use the class like `GuessStatsMessage.make_message('foo', 10)` instead of instantiating the class. @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, the python implementation reads like Java, and isn't Pythonic. How can we improve it?

## This isn't a `class`

It looks like one, and it has a `class` definition, but it's really two functions, one of which is `__init__`. The other "private" methods are just `if` statements.

Let's refactor this as a single function:

```py
def make_message(candidate, count):
    if not count:
        number, verb, plural = 'no', 'are', 's'
    elif count == 1:
        number, verb, plural = count, 'is', ''
    else:
        number, verb, plural = count, 'are', 's'

    message = f'There {verb} {number} {candidate}{plural}'

    return message
```

Now you can simply do:

```py
print(make_message('Foo', 2))
There are 2 Foos
```

Or

```py
msg = make_message('Bar', 3)
print(msg)
There are 3 Bars
```

Now, the `number`, `verb` and `plural` names aren't able to be accessed by anything outside the function, not that we needed the privacy model anyways. There are also fewer methods to read and maintain, your eye isn't jumping between code blocks.

The naming is short and concise, and the code is pretty easy to reason about.

We've also used the `if not count` idiom, where a `0` behaves like `False` and nonzero values act like `True`.

Lastly, the tuple unpacking used for `number, verb, plural` is a very common technique for defining multiple variables inline.

## Docstrings and Type Hints

We could further enhance the readability of this function by adding a docstring and type annotations for our variables:

```py
def make_message(candidate: str, count: int) -> str:
    """Returns a message for a number of objects with the name candidate"""
    ...
```

Comment: _very common technique for defining multiple static variables_ - OK, but those aren't statics.

Comment: @Reinderien yeah, not the best choice of words, I'll make an edit